# Heroku deploy - could not read Username

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-cli

I have problem with deploying application, I've tried:

```
git push -f git@heroku.com:<<application-name>>.git master
```

and also

```
env GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1 git push -f git@heroku.com:<<application-name>>.git master
```

But I'm getting output with:

```
Exit code: 128
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

I know what happened, we had

```
https://github.com/<<org>>/<<repo>>",
```

in our package.json. And this repository became private.